# Objective-C "message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am calling an In App purchase in my view, but it keeps crashing when the user is pressing the `buyButton` and I'm not sure why this is. The crash I am getting:

```
2014-01-25 15:57:54.625 MyApp[563:60b] *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1a027b50
```

**This is my code:**

```
{
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSArray *_products;
    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [RageIAPHelper sharedInstance];
    _products = nil;
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:0];

            _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
            [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
            [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

            NSString *priceString = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];                    
            }
            ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]);
        }
    }];
}


- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *buyAdButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyAdButton.tag];
    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
}

@end
```

**Crashes here**

```
 SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyAdButton.tag];
```

Comment: Please narrow this down to only relevant bits of code.

Comment: add Exeption breakpoint please

Comment: Updated to relevant code only. I added a Exception break point, the line it's crashing on is in the question now

Comment: please add in `buyButtonTapped` method the condition `if(_products) { // here get the object from array}` i guess that `_products` in this method is nil

Comment: maybe try `_products = [NSArray arrayWithArray:products];`.  I'm not sure about the return block, it may clean up it's array even if it's reference count is not 0.

Comment: Add property declaration for _products please

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Also, I bet you didn't spend a minute googling the error message. This is an extremely common and over-asked problem, there are dozens (if not hundreds) of duplicates. Make some effort.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with in-app purchase.

Answer (score 2):

That message is coming from Zombies. Turn Zombies off.

If you're not using ARC, use it! With ARC, memory is managed correctly for you, so as to prevent just this kind of thing, i.e. sending a message to a deallocated instance.

If you *are* using ARC, then you are thwarting it by mismanaging the memory for `_products`; perhaps you have declared `_products` as a weak (unsafe unretained) reference.

Also, run the Analyzer. It will point out the potential for this sort of thing. It understands memory management better than a human being does.

Comment: "With ARC, this absolutely cannot happen" - ***Wrong.***